# Load a 'php://temp' or 'php://memory' file within a Symfony File object

Tags: php, file, symfony

I have a blob resource from my db. I want to wrap temporaly this file into Symfony File object because I want to use specific methods like the extension guesser, and apply symfony file validators.
I want to store this temporary file into memory, because the blobs are small files and i dont want to create a file in disk in every request.

I tried to do this in that way:

```
$file = new File ('php://temp');
```

but symfony throws an error that says 'The file "php://temp" does not exist'. Looking at File source, the error is caused by a "is_file($path)" check that is made in the constructor, and I can invalidate this putting false in the second argument. But, if I do:

```
$file = new File ('php://temp', false);
```

the File is created, but then the error comes back later, e.g. when i use the guesser:

```
$file->guessExtension($file)
```

because in Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeGuesser.php:

```
public function guess($path)
    {
        if (!is_file($path)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
        }
 (...)
```

Ok. Then my question is: There is a way to load a 'php://temp' or 'php://memory' within a File object?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure php://temp writes to memory until it is full and then writes to a file, whereas php://memory ensures only in memory with no fall back.

Answer (score 0):

This likely happens because `php://temp` and `php://memory` are non-reusable, so once you've written to it the content may not still be there when you next want it. From the PHP manual:

> php://memory and php://temp are not reusable, i.e. after the streams have been closed there is no way to refer to them again.
>
> ```
> file_put_contents('php://memory', 'PHP');
> echo file_get_contents('php://memory'); // prints nothing
> ```

How are you writing to `php://temp` to begin with? That will be the more important issue rather than with Symfony's `File` class. I suspect that by the time you are creating a `File` instance that `php://temp` has already gone.

It's worth noting that using `php://temp` will create a file on disk in the temporary location, so you might as well use write to a [tempnam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) handle anyway. At least then you will have a reference to a physical (but temporary) file.

Comment: link to the doc the extract above was taken from, just in case: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to allow passing the file *contents* (instead of the path) to Symfony's MIME type guesser, to enable guessing "on-the-fly": https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40916

Here's how I do it right now:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Mime\MimeTypes;

$tmpFilename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'guessMimeType_');
file_put_contents($tmpFilename, $content);
$mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
$guessedMimeType = $mimeTypes->guessMimeType($tmpFilename);
unlink($tmpFilename);
```

The first line is taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#93256